# Hadoop is configured to use IP address but still connect to localhost

Tags: hadoop

I have configured Hadoop to use IP address instead of localhost but when I started it, it still posted an error that can not ssh to localhost.

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///<hdfs_path>/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///<hdfs_path>/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://<IP_address>/</value>  
<description>NameNode URI</description>
```

When I started Hadoop, the below error appeared:

```
localhost: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

When I tried to allow shh to localhost in our test server, the error disappeared. But problem is that in our production server, ssh to localhost is not allowed. I tried to avoid using localhost and use IP address instead, but why Hadoop still needs to ssh to localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Only the `start-dfs`, `start-yarn`, or `start-all` shell scripts use SSH, and the SSH connection has nothing to do with the XML files.

That's not required; you can run `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode`, and the YARN daemon processes directly. However, you'll still need to somehow get into a shell of each machine to run those commands, if they don't start at boot or ever fail to (re)start

Comment: Seems that your comment did not answer my question. We know that Hadoop uses ssh to communicate with data nodes. My problem is that I want it to use IP address instead of hostname (localhost). So I have configured the core-site.xml file to use IP. But it still used localhost as hostname when connect ssh, which caused that error.

Comment: No, it uses RPC to communicate with datanodes, not SSH. Like I said, the XML files have nothing to do with SSH configuration. You cannot make it use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" for those scripts. My answer says not to use those "start scripts", in fact

Comment: Ok you are right. I have tried to start Hadoop successfully without ssh using your suggestion. But I am not sure if other functions can run correctly without ssh.

Comment: As mentioned, Hadoop uses its own RPC protocols, not SSH. The only problem you'll have is performing regular Linux admin tasks like installing extra software, upgrading / restarting services, or extracting logs